# Generators of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory

How do I show that a set of closed sets (plus the empty set) is a generator for $\mathbb{B}_2$? The set in question is the set made of set of vectors in a given range of angles and lengths, think of it as a slice of pizza with the tip at the origon.

All the proofs I've seen are for open sets, namely the set of open (or half open) rectangles with rationals endpoints. So how do I translate the method used for those to closed sets?

Comment: Show that you can create an open rectangle from countable unions of closed rectangles.

Comment: and also the other way around right? closed rec as open recs. Now that I have the set of closed rectangles as a generator, how do then show my set is closed? My set doesn't have rational endpoints, and since they aren't open it isn't stable under any unions..

Comment: Just to clarify, are the sets the collection of all closed sectors whose tip is at the origin?

Comment: The elements of the set is the empty set and sets of $A(\theta,\eta,r,R)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid arg(x)\in[\theta,\eta]\subset[0,2\pi), ||x||\in[r,R]\subset(0,\infty)\}$. I could be wrong about the arg part, but it's essential the angle function from the first axis going counterclock wise. defined on R^2\{0}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be open and let $\mathcal A$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra
generated by the sets $A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)$.

Then: $$U-\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\} =\bigcup\left\{ A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)\mid\theta,\eta\in[0,2\pi)\cap \mathbb Q\wedge r,R\in\mathbb{Q}_{+}\wedge A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)\subset U\right\} $$

It comes to the observation that for every element $u\in U-\{(0,0)\}$ we can find a set $A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)$ with rational arguments s.t. it is a subset of $U-\{(0,0)\}$ and contains element $u$.

This is a countable union of sets in $\mathcal A$, so $U-\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\} \in\mathcal{A}$.

Then also $\{(0,0)\}\in\mathcal{A}$ as complement of $\mathbb R-\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\}$ and consequently $U\in\mathcal A$.

So $\mathcal A$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra wich is generated by open sets. Also every set on $\mathcal A$ is a Borelset (it is closed) and proved is now that $\mathcal A$ **is** the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks great. What is the Q that intersect with [0,2pi)? The set of rationls? And you got $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0,0\}$ by having a countable unions of something like $A(0,2\pi-1/n,1/n,n)$? Also, is the set with rational endpoints now open?

Comment: $2\pi-\frac{1}{n}$ is not rational. I took rationals, but you can take any subset of $\mathbb R$ that is dense and countable. The sets $A(....)$ are all closed. This because they are intersections of preimages of closed sets under continuous functions: $\arg$ and $\left\Vert \right\Vert $.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. How do we know that for every element in U we can find a A that is a subset of U that contains u? actually I think I've got it after just asking that hehe. I guess you can just have A to be inside the open ball around u

Comment: Do you agree on this: for every $u\in U-\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\} $
with $U$ open we can find a $A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)$ with
$u\in A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)\subset U-\left\{ \left(0,0\right)\right\} $?
That actually does the job. The fact that the sets $A\left(\theta,\eta,r,R\right)$
are closed does not play an essential part in this and is not disturbing.

Comment: yeah I got it now :D

Answer (score 1):

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets.

Suppose ${\cal S}\subset {\cal B}$ is a countable collection of sets such that for any open set $U$ and for any $x \in U$, there is some $A \in {\cal S}$ such that $x \in A \subset U$. Then we have $\sigma({\cal S}) = {\cal B}$.

To see this, note that $U = \cup_{O\in S, O \subset U} O$, and since this union is countable, we have $U \in \sigma({\cal S})$ and so $\sigma({\cal S})$ contains the open sets and hence ${\cal B} \subset \sigma({\cal S})$, and
since ${\cal S}\subset {\cal B}$, we have $\sigma({\cal S}) = {\cal B}$.

Now let ${\cal C}$ be the collection of closed sectors of the form
$A(q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \arg x \in [q_1, q_2], \|x\| \in [q_3, q_4] \}$, where $q_1, q_2 \in [0, 2 \pi)\cap \mathbb{Q}$
and $q_3, q_4 \in (0, \infty)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Note that 0 is missing from these sets, however, since $\cup_n A({1 \over n}, n, 0, \theta_n) = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ (where $\theta_n$ is an increasing sequence of rationals such that $\theta_n \to 2 \pi$), we see that $\{0\}$ must be in any $\sigma$-algebra containing ${\cal C}$. Hence we let $S= C \cup \{ \{0 \} \}$
(just to shoe horn into the result above).

It is straightforward to verify that ${\cal S}$ satisfies the condition above hence we have the desired result.

To see the latter, suppose $U$ is open and let $x \in U$. If $x=0$, then take $\{0\} \in {\cal S}$, so suppose $x \neq 0$. The function $\phi:[0,\infty)\times [0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\phi(x) = (x_1 \cos x_2, x_1 \sin x_2)$ is continuous, and there is some $p$ such that $\phi(p) = x$.
Hence there is some open $V\subset [0,\infty)\times [0, 2\pi)$ such that $\phi(V) \subset U$ and $p \in V$. Hence we can find rationals $q_1,...,q_4$ such that $p \in [q_1,q_2] \times [q_2, q_3] \subset V$, and we see that
$\phi([q_1,q_2] \times [q_2, q_3]) = A(q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4)$. Hence $x = \phi(p) \in A(q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4) \subset U$.